# Problem: Transparent colour in recent-screens thumbnails is replaced with dark grey. (Android)

Tags: android, thumbnails, transparent, google-keep, recent-screens

I have a transparent app. Thumbnail of my app that appears in recent screens replaces transparency with dark grey colour.
I know that it's possible to have real transparency in this situation because Google Keep has it for its sharing screen (when you share text to the Google Keep App). Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is only an issue on a simulator. Testing on real device removed the problem.